# Excel Worksheet open only specific domain controller

Tags: vba, excel, authentication

I would like to discover how to avoid worksheet opening differemt my enviromente Domain Controller.

E.g 
My netbios DC is contoso.com. 
If someone catch such file and try to open elsewhere the worksheet wont open. 
Or DC authentication before open. I worked too hard creating a code.

I tried https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/326340. Doesnt work.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the `Environ` command which gives VBA access to Windows environment variables on the local machine. There's an environment variable called `LOGONSERVER` that returns the machine name of the Domain Controller used to logon the current user. To access from VBA use:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim strDomainController As String
    strDomainController = Environ("LOGONSERVER")
    Debug.Print strDomainController
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Robin. I'm sorry the delay I were in a big migration. About the code I didn't understando can you provide another way/ explanation of what could I do ?I copied and paste the code in vba enviroment and ran the code nothing occured.